# JSON for Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to read this JSON URL: `http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?url=https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hazretiyasuo`

My code:

```
geourl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hazretiyasuo"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(geourl)
content = response.read()
data = json.loads(content.decode("utf8"))
for row in data['stream']
    print data['game']
```

I can read `'stream'` but i cant read `'game'`, game is inside of stream.

Comment: sorry for my english bad. need read json page and control stream on/off. i can readn "stream" and i cant read "game" :/

Comment: what do you see if you `print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, sort_keys=True))`?

Comment: no, need only "game" look pls: http://prntscr.com/4zlff9

Comment: my previous comment is not the solution. It is the debugging suggestion. Don't use screenshots. Post the json output as a text instead. The output should tell you that `data['stream']['channel']['game']` should be used. You should become more familiar with Python dictionaries if the answer is not obvious to you. Dictionaries are very common in Python; you should know how to use them.

Comment: hm ok look : http://paste.ubuntu.com/8673105/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized (how to get a particular value from a particular json object).

Comment: pls help me im control stream on/off

Comment: what happens if you add `print(data['stream']['channel']['game'])` after `data = json.loads(content.decode())` line?

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code in the question and then print out the json that gets returned, I get the following:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hazretiyasuo",
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hazretiyasuo"
  },
  "stream": null
}
```

The reason you can't get `data['game']` is because the json you get back does not contain that information.